# tinymce code highlighting just like stackoverflow?

Tags: php, jquery, tinymce, codehighlighter

im using tinymce for my text editor, i wanted a code highlighting feature for one of the buttons on the toolbar, but i wanted a simple one like the one stackoverflow uses, deos anybody know of anything out there, or deos tinymce have something like this build in :)) thanks for the support!

p.s. im using the jquery tinymce

Comment: FWIW, SO's syntax highlighting sucks terribly. You should look at the SQL, Haskell or Lisp tags.

Comment: Is your question about code **highlighting** (coloring), or about **marking code** as code by indenting it by 4 spaces? These are two discrete problems.

Comment: oh okay, but i just wanted a simple syntax highlighter, like stackoverflow

Comment: @deceze i think both, like i said something simple like stackoverflow!!! :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stackoverflow uses the markup language [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/). Server-side it's "rendered" by [MarkdownSharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/) (C# implementation, but there are [PHP ports](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/) as well). The client-side text editor is [WMD](http://wmd-editor.com/).

Syntax highlighting is done using [code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/).

See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network.

You probably won't be able to easily fold this into TinyMCE. You're either using Markdown, or a WYSIWYG text editor. Both at the same time is a contradiction.